# Html entities converrsion in onchange function in php

Tags: php, html, cakephp, web-development-server, html-entities

When I try to pass variables to check_holiday_dates_on_application I want them to be surrounded by ' in the site html. This is what my code looks like:

```
'onchange' => 'return check_holiday_dates_on_application(\'' . $this->Url->webroot('') . '\', \'' . $token . '\',' . json_encode($abstractionDayList) . '\');']); ?>
```

What I want is

```
onchange="return check_holiday_dates_on_application('webroot',token','abstractionDayList');"
```

What I get is

```
onchange="return check_holiday_dates_on_application(&#039;webroot&#039;, &#039;token&#039;,abstractionDayList&#039;);"
```

Can anyone help me out?

Comment: Please provide a little more context around what you're passing this to, and also include the exact version number of the CakePHP framework you're using. Looks like you probably need to pass `'escape' => false` as an option but exactly how would depend on the specifics of what you're doing here.

Comment: `'escape' => false` did the trick, thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Worked with setting the parameter

```
'escape' => false
```

Thanks for the answer @Greg Schmidt in the comments.

Answer (score 0):

Try this, hope it helps

```
'onchange' => 'return check_holiday_dates_on_application(\'' . $this->Url->webroot('') . '\', \'' . $token . '\', ' . json_encode($abstractionDayList) . ');'
```

Comment: This unfortunately does not work, the output is still the same